# Subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Describe explicitly all the subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{3}$ where $\mathbb{F}_{2}$ is the field with two elements.

In this case I know the dim $\mathbb{F}_{2}^{3}$ is 3 and there are $2^3$ elements such that 
$\{[0, 0, 0]^T,[0,1,0]^T,[0,0,1]^T,[0,1,1]^T,[1,0,0]^T,[1,1,0]^T,[1,0,1]^T,[1,1,1]^T\}$.

I do not know how to get all the subspaces of this. Could you please give a hint?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked the properties that a subset must satisfy in order to be a subspace?

Comment: Have you found _any_ subspaces? Start looking, and you might find a lot of them. Maybe even figure out how to find all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Since $\dim(\mathbb{F}_{2}^{3})=3$, any non-trivial subspace must have dimension 1 or 2.

A $1$-dimensional subspace is the span of a non-zero vector.

A $2$-dimensional subspace is the span of two linearly independent vectors $u,v$.
This must have $4$ elements, which have to be $\{ 0 , u , v , u+v \}$.

Note here, that for the vectors to be linearly independent they need not to be scalar multiple of eachother. Since the only scalars are $0,1$, you can easily check that $u,v$ are linearly independent exactly when $u \neq 0, v \neq 0, u \neq v$, that is they are distinct non-zero vectors.

Finally, note that if $u,v$ are distinct non-zero vectors than $\mbox{Span} \{ u, v \}=\mbox{Span} \{ u, u+v \}=\mbox{Span} \{ u+v, v \}$, thus you have fewer subspaces than pairs of vectors.

And don't forget the trivial subspaces.

Comment: Thank you. I got this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the subspaces are the point (origin), the 'lines' (consisting of any point and the origin), the 'planes' (having any two nonzero points, their sum and the origin), and the whole space.